# Implementing F# interface types that have methods with generic type parameters

Tags: f#

In the [Use interfaces to group related operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-interfaces-to-group-related-operations) section of the F# component design guidelines, it lists this interface type that has methods with a generic type parameter, `'T`.

```
type Serializer =
    abstract Serialize<'T> : preserveRefEq: bool -> value: 'T -> string
    abstract Deserialize<'T> : preserveRefEq: bool -> pickle: string -> 'T
```

The [object expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions) reference section and the [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces) reference section don't list any example of how to implement an interface with a generic `'T` parameter. The [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/) reference section does have a brief example at the end of the section... I'm still having difficulty writing code that mirrors that example.

I know how to implement an interface with a generic type, just not an interface with a generic type parameter.

Here's a simple toy example I've been trying to implement to understand how to do this:

```
type Foo = Foo of string
type Bar = Bar of string

let unwrapFoo (Foo foo) = foo
let unwrapBar (Bar bar) = bar

type IWrapper =
    abstract member Unwrap<'T> : 'T -> string
    abstract member Wrap<'U> : string -> 'U
```

Trying to implement the `IWrapper` is where I'm running into compiler errors:

```
let wrapper =
    { new IWrapper with
        member this.Unwrap<Foo>(foo: Foo) = unwrapFoo foo
        member this.Wrap<Bar> string = Bar string }
```

The `wrapper` let binding will give me back a compiler error: `Unexpected identifier in pattern. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.`

[image: Unexpected identifier in pattern. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.]

My other attempt at implementing `IWrapper` gives me this compiler error: `typecheck error The member 'Unwrap<'T> : Foo -> string' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required signature is 'Unwrap<'T> : 'T -> string'.`

```
let wrapper =
    { new IWrapper with
        member this.Unwrap<'T>(foo: Foo) = unwrapFoo foo
        member this.Wrap<'U> string = Bar(string) }
```

[image: typecheck error The member 'Unwrap<'T> : Foo -> string' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required signature is 'Unwrap<'T> : 'T -> string'.]

Any help implementing this interface type and insight into reading the compiler error messages (which I'm sure is explaining to me how to solve my problem) is greatly appreciated. Thanks peeps!

Comment: Your declaration should be `member this.Unwrap<'T>(foo: 'T) = ...` although you won't be able to call `unwrapFoo` since `foo` has the wrong type. `Wrap` and `Unwrap` need to work for all types so you can't specialise the implementation to some particular type like `Foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic signature doesn't mean what you think it means.

It doesn't mean "*I will take **some** type as parameter. Don't know what that type is yet, I'll decide later, but for now let's call it `'T`*." That's not what it means.

Instead it means "*Pick a type, any type. I don't know what you're going to pick, so for now let's call it `'T`. Picked the type yet? Good! Now I'll take a parameter of that type*"

In other words, it's the *caller* of the function who's picking the type parameter, not the implementer.

Compare with other generic functions. Let's take `List.length` for example. It has the following signature:

```
List.length<'a> : 'a list -> int
```

This signature says: "*Pick any type `'a`. Any type, I don't care which. Then I'll take a list of type `'a list` and return you an `int`*"

Its implementer isn't free to decide to take some specific list as parameter - e.g. `int list`, - no, they have to write the function in a way that works for any type. Because that's what the type signature promises.

This means that, if you have your `IWrapper` interface defined the way you defined it, the methods have to be able to accept *any* type, not just `Foo` and `Bar`. Because that's what the methods' type signatures promise.

---

But it seems to me that what you really meant to do was to create a type-specific wrapper. A wrapper that can wrap and unwrap some specific two types, not just any types in general. Is that the case?

If that is the case, then the type parameters should be on the interface, not on the methods:

```
type IWrapper<'T, 'U> =
    abstract member Unwrap : 'T -> string
    abstract member Wrap : string -> 'U
```

This definition says "*if you have yourself an instance of `IWrapper<a, b>`, then you can use it to unwrap `a` or to wrap `b`, and nothing else*"

Now you can create a wrapper specifically for `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
let foobarWrapper =
    { new IWrapper<Foo, Bar> with
        member this.Unwrap foo = unwrapFoo foo
        member this.Wrap string = Bar string }
```